# Queries regarding Oracle Siebel Testing

Tags: oracle, testing, automation, siebel, test-framework

I am new to Oracle Siebel testing. I have read about Oracle Application Testing Suite which can be used for testing Siebel.

I have gone through Oracle videos regarding application testing suite and found below which can be used for Siebel testing:
1. Oracle functional testing (OFT) using openscript
2. Oracle Load and performance testing

I have went through following links:
https://blogs.oracle.com/aamat/entry/siebel_test_automation
http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/ATS9_Siebel_Testing_Accelerators/041210_88547/index.htm
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/twp-ats-test-siebel-133042.pdf
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/ds-application-1.pdf

I have below queries :

1. Is there any other efficient way of testing Siebel application or is ATS best way to start for Siebel.
2. Also, what are the frameworks which can be used in ATS ?
3. IS there sample ATS framework available for Siebel?
4. Is there any guide or walk-through available which can help in doing a POC for it ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to proceed is to use ATS test Accelerator

The Testing Accelerator for Siebel includes a Test Starter Kit for Siebel 8.1.1, providing example test automation scripts for functional as well as load / performance testing. The test scripts may be used as templates in order for testers to better understand how to script against Siebel applications or they may be modified to work against your own customized Siebel environment and speed up your testing process.

Visit this URL to download Oracle Testing Accelerator for Oracle Siebel: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/apptesting931-1610487.html

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ATS is the official tool to automate Siebel GUI.

There are 2 different Siebel GUI, one is the old HI/SI, which is activeX and need IE to view. another one is called OpenUI, which is pure web.

Oracle ATS both support them, following video at Oracle show how to test Siebel.

the first one is created by me. and the last two for load testing Siebel.

https://otube.oracle.com/media/Siebel+OpenUI+functional+testing+new+feature++in+OATS+13.1.0.1+by+Sophia+Du/0_eya24f4k/2902

https://otube.oracle.com/media/Siebel+load+testing+%28Part+IA+creating+load+script%29/0_2hlxkxa6/2902

https://otube.oracle.com/media/Siebel+Load+Testing+%28Part+IIA+How+to+Do+Performance+Testing+for+Siebel+OpenUI+Application%29+by+Anna+Huang/0_raccbegx/2902